# In k-means clustering, is the marginal sum of squared distances decreasing?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

Suppose I have a set of data, and let SSD(n) be the sum of squared distances when we assume n clusters.  My question is the following: Is the marginal SSD always decreasing in n.  In other words, is the function f(n) defined as

f(n)=SSD(n)-SSD(n+1)

decreasing in n. This would mean the benefit of adding each additional cluster is decreasing.  I am trying to find either a proof or a simple counterexample.

I have done some simulations with random data, and it always seems to be true.

Comment: Don't test such assumptions on random data. Instead, use highly structured data.

Comment: Any thoughts on what "highly structured data" should be used?

Comment: Try using m very tight clusters placed on a circle. I can imagine there is a drop from n=m-1 to n=m that is much bigger than the gain from m-2 to m-1.